# IIS 8.5 ThreadAbortException

Tags: 64-bit, iis-8.5, threadabortexception

I moved all my existing web application from windows 2003 server(32 bit) IIS 6 to Windows 2012 server(64 bit) IIS 8. .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0. I want to keep application pool in integrated mode. I fixed lot of other issues after migration. I still get ThreadAbortException when Response.Redirect is called. I know setting endResponse to false will fix. Can't imagine doing that in all the pages. Is there a simpler way to do this. Maybe something in config file .

Comment: I had to do it hard way. Replace Response.Redirect(Url) to Response.Redirect(Url, endResponse); context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteResponse();